# Expo does not stop reloading after some Errors

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-emulator, expo

I wanted to share a very annoying problem I have with Expo React-Native. It does not break the app or something but it is just annoying to work with.

I am using Expo and I am using the Android Studio Emulator. Expo is installed on a Virtuall Device and its working properly, however I have this problem for a longer time I think since ReactNative 0.61(or 0.60) when they implemented "Fast Refresh". There are time "Fast Refresh" does work right but sometimes when changing a small thing u get an Error thats something like:

```
Attempted to assign to readonly property.
```

When you reload the app so the error goes away expo shows a white screen with an endless blue spinner... It's just annoying to quit the node server, close the app, open devops in a browser and bring everything back up everytime.

Has anybody experienced the same behavior or knows a fix for this ?

Comment: problem is in your code.this problem says that you are assigning a value to readonly   variable

Comment: add your code so , we can correct you

Comment: Its not a problem in my code - if i reload the whole app it works with the changes i just made. My problem is that its annoying that i have to restart with: `expo start` but it works after.